# Spring - Allow multiple authentications from the same user during the same runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I have recently implemented a token-based security configuration in my Spring Server and it works fine when authenticating for the first time and making requests.

I'm using a software written in Python that will make an authentication request first and after that send multiple requests to save data in the Database.

The issue I'm having is: after running the script, (which, remember, executes very well for the first time), I can no longer authenticate when running it again.

I've tried adding some things like `.logout()` and removing the session cookies from the `SecurityFilterChain` but to no avail. How can I enable multiple authentications per session for the same user in Spring?

Below is my `SecurityFilterChain` bean in `SecurityConfig.java`:

```java
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/**/auth/**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
                .logout()
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .rememberMe()
                .and()
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
            .addFilterBefore(
                    jwtAuthFilter,
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class
            );
        return http.build();
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting from the repeated authentication attempts? Have you tried debugging the `jwtAuthFilter` in this case?

Comment: @kidney I get the following: `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: Range [7, 6) out of bounds for length 6. I reckon this has to do with the `Bearer` token and acquiring it from the String. In this case, however, there is no token, since the authentication failed. The Python script authenticates first and, before checking if it was successful, tries to POST again, hence that error. But besides that, nothing shows up in the console when authenticating, only when processing the other resquests.

Comment: Ok, but if the authentication failed, it should at least tell you why. What kind of response do you get from the authentication request? You can always put a breakpoint in `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` and see why the authentication fails.

Comment: I'll try doing that, thanks. It returns 403 - Forbidden.